# PEAP profile connect without manually entering username and password

Tags: xml, windows, visual-studio, command-line

I am using windows 10,

I want to connect to EAP-PEAP profile using only XML file and netsh commands

I don't want to enter username and password manually

After netsh WLAN add profile command, can you give any method to set username and password through command or code or API or XML file, so that just by giving netsh WLAN connect command my device should connect to EAP profile without asking for username and password?????

I am doing this for testing purpose, so please anyone suggest any method???
[andrewsi](/questions/tagged/andrewsi) [pang](/questions/tagged/pang) [giles](/questions/tagged/giles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to connect to a EAP profile without entering user name and password manually.

I took hex value of username and password and created a profile corresponding .reg file and imported it to registers .

It worked for me :)

Comment: Can you add more detail to this? A sample of the .reg file would be perfect. Thanks.